# Only show portion of large single HTML file

Tags: html, optimization, html-rendering

Note: Asking to delete or modify the file to be smaller than what it is now is not on the table. For archival purposes, the entire file's current contents needs to be preserved.

The file uses at most 20 lines of JS, where they're only there for styling purposes. From what I can find in the file, there are no large images (>500x500) within the file.

Context: I've been asked by someone to help backup their chat history, and allow them to view their history using only their browser via a single HTML file. That part has been handled.

Problem: The single HTML file comes in at 43 MB, and to render the entire file would take up 1.1 GB of RAM. Using querySelectorAll('*') has the node count near 500k, and it can't be loaded on my IPhone (6).

I know its possible to only render html visible within the viewport, but I can't remember the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "EASY" way to render only the viewport part of the html (like a setting, header of some such). Web chats as you might have noticed, don't bring the entire history with them, but make ajax calls as the users scroll up.

If you have images on the page, then you can use some techniques to load them on viewport as can be seen here:https://css-tricks.com/the-complete-guide-to-lazy-loading-images/

One of the suggestions for lazy loading elements is this: https://github.com/malchata/yall.js

You can add some minimal javascript and apply lazy loading on a wide range of html elements, but it's going to need some development effort.

Comment: The problem is (and my brain won't let this go), I definitely remember a Google I/O video where a rep from Twitter was talking about a new html tag that would make it only render content viewable within the viewport.

Comment: My guess is that all these libraries and effort would not have been made if there was such an easy way to achieve it. It might be in the making but I could not find anything in the HTML 5 specification that did it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. It was a talk on <virtual-scroller>. [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtD41bn6kJ0)

Edit 1: ...currently very disappointed. It seems that [no browser supports this](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5673195159945216), which means that I'll need to polyfill it in.

Edit 2: There seems to be implementations made in Vue on this....but I'll need to make significant changes to make it work in plain HTML.

Edit 3: Seems that nothing I do with my bodged prototype reduces the RAM usage, without changing the layout. Shelving this for now.... :(

Comment: Seems it never will be implemented. It was just an idea.